# Why is implicit typing disallowed in non-local variable declarations?

Tags: c#, variables, types, implicit-declaration

I changed this:

```
List<string> chapterNames = new List<string>();
```

...to this:

```
var chapterNames = new List<string>();
```

...and was jabbed with this message from the compiler:

"*The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration*"

Comment: Implicit typing is *only* allowed in local variable declarations. You might wanna fix the title of your question.

Comment: Use or use not...there is no why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is because that's how Microsoft introduced the var keyword in the specification for .NET 3.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx